# Misaligned "Unregistered" characterization

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The "Unregistered" tag on the [user profile page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/18527/caseybatts) is misaligned to the rest of the text:

> [image]

(I also checked the moderator(s) and their "moderator" tag is properly aligned.)

Answer (score 3):

I pushed a fix for this, will be on live after our next production build.